# Passar vetor como argumento para uma função

Tags: c, array, funções

Eu estou tentando passar um vetor para uma função em C, mas não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Como o código é pequeno, vou postar inteiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calcula(double A){
    if(A<=10.0){
        resposta = A;
    }

    return resposta;
}

int main(){     
    double A[100];
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=99; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &A[i]);
    }      

    for(i=0; i<=99; i++){
        calcula(A[i]);
        printf("A[%d] = %.1lf\n",i, A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você quer passar um array para qual função? A função `calcula`? E o que essa função tem que fazer? Dizer se o elemento recebido é menor ou igual a 10? Encontrar o primeiro elemento com valor menor ou igual a 10? Dizer quais são os elementos com valor menor ou igual a 10? O seu código é fácil e seu problema é simples, mas primeiro precisamos saber exatamente o que você está tentando fazer exatamente para podermos ajudar.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Este código não faz muito sentido, a pergunta faz menos ainda.

Não está passando um vetor, está passando um valor único. Se quer passar um vetor faça isso e trate ele, mas tudo indica que só que passar o valor mesmo, e isto está correto.

O que está errado é o código interno da função. Primeiro que fazer comparação relacional com um número `double` nem sempre dá certo, ele não tem exatidão. Segundo está colocando um valor em `resposta` e essa variável sequer existe. por isso o compilador deve estar informando isso. Se for isto a variável nem é necessária.

Mesmo que declare uma variável precisa inicializar com um valor inválido. Qual seria ele? 0? Um negativo? Um NaN? Outra coisa? Aí teria que mudar o tipo de retorno.

Pra falar a verdade talvez deveria só retornar verdadeiro ou falso, ou nem isso já que o código é simples demais. Não importa o que retorne se tiver que filtrar algo na `main()` tem que ter um `if` ali também, caso contrário, até funciona, desde que escolha um valor que será o inválido, mas ele será impresso normalmente se não tiver um filtro.

Não podemos saber exatamente o que o código deveria fazer, então não é possível ajudar mais que isto, mas o erro é este que demonstrei.